# Link to Comments and Review Queue

Tags: support, comments, review, review-queue

How to get links to comments and to the review of a post to be added as "By Review"?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for here? Do you want the link to some comment? If so, the timestamp next to the comment is a link to it. If you want the link to the review item for a post, you'll have to look in the timeline (link beneath vote buttons) and even then the review item is shown only after it has been completed

Comment: @muru Thanks. That is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @muru About the review, what I want to do is add something like: "While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review" Here for the "From Review" part I want to add a link to the review.

Answer (score 4):

Those comments are only generated in the Low Quality Posts review queue, and automatically (you can choose from a list of half a dozen standard comments, or choose to leave no comment at all). You get access to that queue at [2,000 reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/edit).

I agree that these comments can be useful from the First Posts (or Late Answers) queue as well; that's why I use the userscript [AutoReviewComments](https://stackapps.com/q/2116/34061) which gives me similar functionality *everywhere* I can leave a comment (so on the main Q&A pages, but even in the moderator dashboard), and one of the default comments matches what you want to add:

> Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

All you then have to do is copy the link from the current review, which is visible in the address bar:

[image]

and add a `[From Review](https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/xxxxxxx)` at the end of the comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108816/discussion-between-glorfindel-and-sasuke-uchiha).